# Client-side jwt token storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

I need advice, what is the best way to store a JWT token? Should we store in cookies or storages? But with the CSRF flaw and xss attacks I have a doubt. I'm still in training and working on a year-end project. Or the best is to store the jwt token in a variable in a store. I developed the application in nodejs express js for the back and in react for the frontend. Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: You could store the token in a http only cookie. That way it cannot be accessed through javascript at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use cookies, they are easily able to be accessed server side and can have an expiration date.

Take a look at this post: [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)

Comment: thank you so much i will follow this solution